# iphone:button corner radius does not set

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

In my nib file I have chosen one custom button and I want to set its corner radius. I have linked in the QuartzCore framework and then write the following code to set its corner radius

```
[[btnPressureLink layer] setCornerRadius:15.0];
```

and when I add a background colour for the button the corner radius is set but when I put an image on the button the corner radius does not get set.  What should I do to set the corner radius when an image is used on the button?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
 btnPressureLink.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
 [btnPressureLink.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this,

```
[[btnPressureLink layer]setCornerRadius:4.0f];

[[btnPressureLink layer]setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Import Quartz core and try this one....

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 12;
[button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 4

```
self.buttonDone.layer.masksToBounds = true

//round shape
self.buttonDone.layer.cornerRadius = buttonDone.bounds.height/2

//custom shape
self.buttonCancel.layer.cornerRadius = 12
```